# Nuxt.js деплой на сервер

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет! Пытаюсь залить nuxt.js приложение на сервер через npm run build. Сервер выдает 403 ошибку. Подскажите, как задеплоить nuxt приложение на сервер?

Comment: Запустить через `pm2` и настроить прокси через nginx/apache на `localhost:3000`

Comment: Нужны данные с package.json

Answer (score 2):

В оф. документации написано https://ru.nuxtjs.org/guide/commands/

Вы должны добавить эти команды в файл package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nuxt",
  "build": "nuxt build",
  "start": "nuxt start",
  "generate" "nuxt generate"
}
```

в консоли пишите npm run generate и у вас в проекте появится папка dist и все содержимое из нее, скопировать на хостинг (Собрать приложение и сгенерировать каждый маршрут в виде HTML файла (используется в случае статического хостинга).